# Questions about objectify's transactionally enqueued tasks

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have some questions about how a transactionally enqueued task works and when it is executed.

Suppose I have some operations in a transaction in this order:

1. Write an entity
2. Write another entity
3. Add work to queue in transaction
4. Write yet another entity

1) If one of the write entity operations fails, the entire transaction fails. Does that mean no work will be enqueued even if it fails at step 4?

2) When is worked added to the queue if all the write operations succeed? As the final step? Or just in the order it appears?

3) What if adding work to the queue fails, is the entire transaction a failure and all the write operations rolled back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, if the transaction rolls back no work will be enqueued.

2) Work is added to the queue as part of the transaction commit. When executing, the queued work is guaranteed to see data in the post-transaction state (unless it was otherwise modified, of course).

3) If adding work to the queue fails (and you don't otherwise catch the exception), the exception will propagate up and cause the transaction to rollback.

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot. Also: does running `ofy().transact(new VoidWork() {}` block the current thread until the transaction is complete? Or is it asynchronous?

Comment: It's synchronous. The async aspects of the API are driven by futures so you can treat the whole API as synchronous. Eg if you call `ofy().load().key(...)` you get back a `Ref`, and the operation is async until you call `get()` on the `Ref`.